# Multiple Regression - effect size

Tags: multiple-regression, effect-size

I want to calculate the effect size of a multiple regression. So far, I used Cohens $f^2$.

Somehow, I wonder, if the effect size expressed by Cohens $f^2$ is an appropriate measurement. Let's assume that $R^2$ is high valued and furthermore strongly biased - $f^2$ will still give me a high effect which is not taking in account how many predictors I included in model and what's the quality of model ("no punishment" for a bad model).

Is there a better approach ("state of the art") to calculate effect size for multiple regression analysis?

Can I calculate the effect size Cohen's $f^2$ of each predictor by using $R^2$ adjusted? Does this make any sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question seems to express the issue of bias mentioned in the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effect_size#Cohen.27s_.C6.922) on effect sizes.  It seems like you are concerned that you regression model will be over parametrized, which $R^2$ does not take into account - as you note, it just gets higher the more parameters you put into it.  Using [adjusted $R^2$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination#Adjusted_R2) would seem to be ok to addresss this problem.

This feature of $R^2$ has been highlighted as a reason not to use $R^2$, normal or adjusted, as part of a **model selection** process.  A possible solution would be to do model selection using an information criteria such as AIC or BIC to arrive at an appropriate regression model from which to take $R^2$ and calculate $f^2$.

Cohen's $f^2$ does not appear to be used that often, but has been recently recommended for use with mixed effects (aka hierarchical or multilevel) multiple regression By Selya et al. (2012): "[A practical guide to calculating Cohen's $f^2$, a measure of local effect size, from PROC MIXED](http://%5Chttp://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3328081/)".

Reporting the effect size for particular parameters instead of just the whole model might be one general solution to the bias issue you raise.  Selya et al. use Cohen's $f^2$ for comparing the effect sizes of **different predictors** within their model.  They specify $f^2$ as

$$
f^2= \frac{{R_{AB}^2} - {R_{A}^2}}{1-{R_A^2}}
$$

Where ${R_{AB}^2}$ is a multiple regression model with all of their predictors, and ${R_{B}^2}$ is a model without the predictor (A) for which they want to calculate a "local" effect size.  ${R_{AB}^2}$ and ${R_{B}^2}$ can be respecified for different focal parameters for comparing several different effect sizes from the same model.  If your are worried that $R^2$ is inflated then this approach should equally penalize all calculations of the effect sizes for individual parameters.

A final thing that comes to mind is that you could calculate a confidence region around $R^2$ and even $f^2$.  This can be done via [bootstrapping](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0264999399000346); there might be packages in `R` that can do this automatically.  I'm not sure if this is actually relevant to the general issue of bias in $R^2$ but it could at least express some degree of uncertainty in how how $R^2$ is.